# How to get stack items by index in c#?

Tags: c#, list, indexing, stack

I am new to C#.
Is it possible to get stack items by index like we can do in Lists in C#?

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve it using LINQ:

```
Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
stack.Push(1);
stack.Push(2);
stack.Push(3);
stack.Push(4);

int top = stack.ElementAt(0); // Returns 4
int next = stack.ElementAt(1); // Returns 3
```

However, if you find youself attempting to access the elements on a stack by index, then you are certainly doing something wrong, and you should redesign your solution.

Comment: I may be wrong, but Stack in C# implemented as an array  and two positions variable start and end (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571(v=vs.80).aspx). 
If that's true, I don't see the problem to get an element by index in similar way how it happens in  simple array.
More to say, I was surprised that there is no such method in the Stack itself and you have to do it via Linq extension .

Comment: This is how I see stack in my debugger. I was confused that stack[0] was the top of the stack. So apparently what I was seeing wasn't the actual underlying array, but ElementAt(0).

Comment: _"However, if you find youself attempting to access the elements on a stack by index, then you are certainly doing something wrong, and you should redesign your solution"_ - this is simply generalizing things too much. There are perfectly valid use cases for having to inspect a stack by index, depending on what you use it for. My use case right now: converting this custom interpreter from Java to C#: http://craftinginterpreters.com/resolving-and-binding.html#resolving-variable-expressions

Comment: I think it would be good to note that `ElementAt` is O(n) and scales terribly.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using ElementAt() as shown by Matias. You can also use Peek to see what is on top without popping it. You can also convert to an array and get a value by index that way.

```
var s = new Stack<int>();
s.Push(1);
s.Push(2);

var value = s.ToArray()[1];
```

You should ask yourself whether this is wise, though. All you will ever be able to do is get a snapshot of the Stack at a point in time. There are also concurrency issues to consider.

**UPDATE:**

Seems like Matias and I came up with very similar answers. His is a more correct answer as to what the question asks. The ToArray() approach gives you a consistent snapshot that may be a bit more stable. Subsequent calls to ElementAt() may give you different answers and may throw an exception if the stack has been popped in between calls.

Comment: It is possible by doing `ElementAt`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to chose the element of the stack by index by calling `ElementAt<T>(Int32)` or `ElementAtOrDefault(Int32)` methods.

As a side note, if you're new to C#, always try to find the answers at

1. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime)
3. [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime)

It's often way faster and more reliable than to look for the information on SO =)

Comment: "It's often way faster and more reliable then look for info on SO =)" - really? Not saying it isn't but why are you answering questions here then. You gonna go suggest this on everything in StackOverflow where there is a related reference to MSDN? Just kinda surprised you bothered to write that...

Comment: Because as I one day found out, lots of people asking basic questions don't know about docs or refsource.