# Is it possible to check if all stack items have the same value?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, stack

I was trying to make a function that returns a boolean: true if all items are the same, false if not. I tought to use a foreach loop to iterate the stack and somehow check if all items are equal or not, but I'm not sure this is the best way.

What i tried is:

```
bool AllSame(Stack<int> myStack)
{
    int check = myStack.Peek();
    foreach(int i in myStack)
        if(i != check)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

The example above was made with integer values to make things simple, but of course these could be any generic values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get stack items by index in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535026/how-to-get-stack-items-by-index-in-c)

Comment: `Stack<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Have you tried using a foreach or LINQ on the Stack itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all items are the same in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307172/check-if-all-items-are-the-same-in-a-list)

Comment: What does "the best way" mean? Fastest, shortest, easiest to understand, easiest to maintain?

Comment: Kind of begs the question why you are using a stack in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a reason to write your own extension method. When writing a LINQ extension method with some unusual element processing (in this case, treat the first element specially) using an `Enumerator` directly is probably best.

```
public static class StackExt {
    public static bool AllSame<T>(this Stack<T> s, IEqualityComparer<T> cmp = null) {
        cmp ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        var se = s.GetEnumerator();
        if (se.MoveNext()) {
            T first = se.Current;
            while (se.MoveNext())
                if (!cmp.Equals(first, se.Current))
                    return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static bool AllSame2<T>(this Stack<T> s, IEqualityComparer<T> cmp = null) => s.Distinct(cmp).Take(2).Count() == 1;
}
```

I also included a LINQ version of the extension method: the LINQ version is shorter, but not as efficient as it has to allocate a `Set<T>` to track what has been seen to implement `Distinct()`, though the `Take(2)` limits the worst performance issue, which is that `Count()` would count all of the elements when you only care if there is one or more than one.

Comment: Would it be better to use `All` instead of `Distinct`? `s.All(x => cmp.Equals(x, s.First()))` would simply iterate and short-circuit when it first encounters a different item.

Comment: @NPras You would need to cache `s.First()` instead of calling it per comparison and you would need to handle default for `cmp` - `Stack<T>` doesn't implement any special cases so `First()` has to create an iterator and iterate to the first item. `s.First() is var first && (cmp ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default) is var ucmp && s.All(x => ucmp.Equals(x, first))` You are also doing an unnecessary comparison of `first` against `first`. Probably a wash.